# why error with if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I earlier asked a question about a `xmlHttp.send()` code that wasn't working. I thought I had fixed all of it, but now I've got another problem.

In the `handleServerResponse()` function, the code errors out in the `if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) and if (xmlHttp.readyState == 200)`. Why is it doing that? An example php code is under the JavaScript.

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

        function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){
            var xmlHttp;

            if(window.ActiveXObject){
                try{
                   xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
                }catch(e){
                    xmlHttp = false;
                }
            }else{
                try{
                   xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }catch(e){
                    xmlHttp = false;
                } 
            }

            if(!xmlHttp){
                alert("cant create that object hos");

            }else{
                return xmlHttp;
            }
        }




function newuser() {

            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 0 || xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
                name = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("name").value);

                queryString = "name=" + name;
                xmlHttp.open("GET", "code/php/core.php?" + queryString, true);
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerRespons;
                xmlHttp.send();
           }else{
               setTimeout('newuser()', 1000)
           }  
    }

    function handleServerRespons(){

        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4){

            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 200){
                alert('1234545');
                xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
                xmlDocumentElement=xmlResponse.documentElement;
                message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;

                alert(message);

                }
            }
        }
```

**php code:**

```
         $name = $_GET['name'];

                      header('Content-Type: text/xml');
                      echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';
                      echo '<response>';
                      echo $name;
                      echo '</response>';
```

Comment: How is the xmlHttp object created, would you mind posting that?  Also, `readyState` will never be 200.

Comment: Did you mean to use the `.status` property?

Comment: if (xmlHttp.status? == 200){  ?

Comment: also get the error: cannot read documentElement. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using a variable (`xmlHttp`) you must use `this` in an `onreadystatechange` event callback
so your function will be:

```
function handleServerRespons() {
  if ( this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200 ) { // and also use "status" here not "readyState"
    xmlResponse = this.responseXML;
    xmlDocumentElement=xmlResponse.documentElement;
    message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
    alert( message );
  }
}
```

or wrap your code with `(function(){...})();` like below

```
(function() {
  // all your code goes here, so you can use that 'xmlHttp' instead of 'this'
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

`xmlHttp.readyState` can't be 200. you should use `xmlHttp.status`.

Comment: ´if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4){

            if (xmlHttp.status == 200){´

Like that?

Comment: @MattisBratland Yes; xmlHttp.status is the statuscode, which should be 200 if the page was loaded correctly (and for example 404 if it wasn't found).

Answer (score 0):

`xmlHttp.readyState` has status of the XMLHttpRequest [The XMLHttpRequest Object](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20060405/)

`xmlHttp.status` will be available when `xmlHttp.readyState` is 3 or 4. When available `xmlHttp.status` should represent the HTTP status code.